# Facebook login, logout and cookies (PHP SDK and Javascript SDK)

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

This is my problem: when the user first enters the application there is no problem ... starts the app witout detected or be authorized user. The application process is as follows:

1. Click on the image to start
2. Click on "Participar" button
3. JavaScript SDK detects no user and shows the pop-up installation and permits.
   Installation: grant permits, fill out the form, submit the form and redirect to the scoring script.

But when the user logs out of facebook, and reconnects with another user from the same IP, something bad happens:

1. Click on the image index (which shows user id 0)
2. Click on "Participar" button:
3. JavaScript SDK detects the user ID that **was logged before from the same IP**.

Then the script join.php automatically redirects them to score.php, and score.php detects no valid id in the database (because they have not been given permissions, nor submitted the form), so it redirects to index.php   Back to the index still indicates user 0: click on "Participar" a second time and then everything works correctly

Anyone know what could be wrong? Scripts and templates are listed below.

PHP Files, in order

1. index.php [pastebin.com/jnCR7dqq](http://pastebin.com/jnCR7dqq)
2. join.php [pastebin.com/YF4xBfAu](http://pastebin.com/YF4xBfAu)
3. score.php [pastebin.com/EcjQWTy1](http://pastebin.com/EcjQWTy1)

HTML Files, in order

1. index.html [pastebin.com/WUqNQx5x](http://pastebin.com/WUqNQx5x) (js cycle between index divs, fake href)
2. join.html [pastebin.com/Qst0JvUT](http://pastebin.com/Qst0JvUT) (js fake a href)
3. score.html [pastebin.com/8ns0XCQW](http://pastebin.com/8ns0XCQW) (js cycle between index divs, fake href)

Answer (score 1):

I was having almost similar problem, removing `cookies` attribute while initialising facebook object fixed it.

change 
`$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_PW, 'cookie' => true));`

to

`$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_PW));`

Comment: Doesnt work. Before ask here I try with your answer, and removing the cookie in Javascript SDK too, but nothing happend :/